# Am I missing some controls for windows mobile?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I'm a C# developer taking my first steps in Windows Mobile development. I've installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and the Windows mobile 6 Pro and Standard SDK's. Now I am trying to create a simple winforms application.

The problem is that when I set the Target Platform to Windows Mobile Standard, I seem to be missing a lot of controls. For example, there is a checkbox, but there isn't even a simple button (take a look at this [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/OWU5ZGNhY2) ). When I switch to Windows Mobile 6 Professional, I get all kinds of controls.

What could be the problem? I've already tried to repair the WM 6 standard SDK, but that did not help.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct.  Windows Mobile Standard, also known as Smartphone, doesn't have a touchscreen.  All interaction is done through the two menu action buttons.  Because of this many controls, like buttons, don't make sense and are therefore filtered from the toolbox.

Comment: Just as I can select a button and browse through various input elements on a web form by keyboard only, it would also be possible to implement the same for windows mobile phones without a touchscreen. That's why I thought that there must be a button. 

How do you replace a simple button? I need something that users can click in order to start an action in my software.

Comment: As Chris Tacke mentioned Windows Mobile Standard edition doesn't officially support button controls (even if the built in browser uses them).

The recommended replacement is to design your application to use the soft key menu bar, or a drill down list style interface. If you look at the built in applications (except the browser) you will notice these all follow this pattern.